# All indices are console logged immediately after rendering - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering an array of images in React using the map function. My goal is to make the image clickable, and log the corresponding index in the console (I'll use that later on to set state). With the code below, all indices are logged immediately after rendering. I'm quite a rookie with React and can't think of a solution nor find one after googling around.

```
import React from 'react';
import './PlaylistGridStyle.css'


const PlaylistGrid = ( props ) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 className='playlistGridHeader'>
                    {props.user.display_name}'s playlists
                </h1>
                <ul className='list'>
                    {props.playlistData.items.map((playlist, index) => {
                        return(
                        <li key={playlist.name} className='item'> 
                            <img src={playlist.images[0].url} alt='Playlist cover' height='250px' width='250px' onClick={console.log(index)}/>
                            <div className='description'>{playlist.name}</div>
                        </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlaylistGrid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work better by doing this, because onClick should be function. In your case, onClick received value of `console.log` being called immediately when rendering the component.

```
<img src={playlist.images[0].url} alt='Playlist cover' height='250px' width='250px' onClick={() => console.log(index)}/>
```

If you need to handle the click in a function, just do this :

```
const PlaylistGrid = ( props ) => {
    const handleClick = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 className='playlistGridHeader'>
                    {props.user.display_name}'s playlists
                </h1>
                <ul className='list'>
                    {props.playlistData.items.map((playlist, index) => {
                        return(
                        <li key={playlist.name} className='item'> 
                            <img src={playlist.images[0].url} alt='Playlist cover' height='250px' width='250px' onClick={() =>handleClick(index)}/>
                            <div className='description'>{playlist.name}</div>
                        </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlaylistGrid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That actually prevents all indices getting logged after rendering. I'm still left with the second part of the issue though: logging the index of the image that was clicked.

Comment: It is working for me aha. I have just tested it :/
As you click on an image, it is logging its index

Comment: It's working now, my bad! Some imported CSS was blocking my click (if that makes any sense). Without that layer of CSS it's actually functioning.